# How can I remove a colon between two numbers in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have a text in this format:

> term: 156:59 datainput

I want to remove the ":" between the number and then replace it with something else so the text can become:

> term: 156-59 datainput

How can I do this in VB.NET?

Comment: Hey at least he didn't try to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In VB.NET (credit Jonathan):

```
    Dim text As String = "term: 156:59 datainput"
    Dim fixedText As String = Regex.Replace(text, "(\d+):(\d+)", "$1-$2")
```

nb: removed last two lines as suggested.

Comment: Probably not necessary to have the last two lines, but #1 for having the first correct answer in VB version.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I know this is a little clumsy, but it should work (assuming your data is in exactly the format you specify):

```
input[input.IndexOf(":", input.IndexOf(":")+1)] = "#"
```

Of course, if you want a more general case to find NUMBER:NUMBER and replace it with NUMBER#NUMBER, I'd recommend using a regular expression, like this:

```
var re = new Regex(@"(\d+):(\d+)");
re.Replace(input, "$1#$2");
```

Comment: Good job spotting the first ":". I think quite few didn't note that one immediately. Including me.

Comment: @Mikko: I can't take credit for noticing that -- I had a post written up linking to string.replace before I saw another answer that had it, and a comment saying it was wrong.

Comment: Whoops... somehow the whole 'VB.Net' thing escaped me...  Sorry about that Rithet.

Comment: No problem, you still got my vote for the first correct answer even though it's in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have read the data in to a string, take a look at the string.replace function.

Comment: How do people keep voting up stuff that is obviously wrong to anyone who read the question carefully?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, there were approximately 5 or so others who did the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this using string replace

Dim data As String = "term: 156:59 datainput"

data = data.Replace(":", "-").Replace("term-", "term:")